# Formula One (Tidestone) question

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, spreadsheetgear

At work we're stuck with using Formula One Excel components. The problem is that I can't find anywhere to post questions so I thought I try here.

What I'm trying to achieve is reading workbooks into sheets. I have multiple vts workbooks that consist of one sheet each and I would like to read them into one workbook with multiple sheets. The only methods i found that takes a vts file name is the Read and ReadEx methods, however those methods only would not allow me to read a single sheet and add it to an existing workbook.

This is the code that I'm using to read a workbook:

```
TTF160.AxTTF160.AxF1Book book = new AxF1Book();
book.ReadEx("book1.vts");
book.ReadEx("book2.vts");
```

But the second read statement replaces the whole workbook. Is there a way to add the second workbook as a worksheet?

Answer (score 0):

Have you investigated whether you can read each file into its own AxF1Book object. Then copy the sheet from one to the other?  If I remember correctly, you may need to put those Book objects into a WorkbookGroup so that they can 'see' each other.